# How do I show pie graph in 2 row and 2 column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, pie-chart

I have a problem about showing pie graphs in 2 row and 2 column. They are listed in one column.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my code snippets shown below.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
coursera_df_beginner["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',shadow=True, explode=(0.1, 0, 0), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', ax=ax1)
plt.title('Difficulty in Courses')
plt.ylabel("")

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
coursera_df_intermediate["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',shadow=True, explode=(0.1, 0, 0), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', ax=ax2)
plt.title('Difficulty in Courses')
plt.ylabel("")

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax3 = plt.subplot(2,2,3)
coursera_df_mixed["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',shadow=True, explode=(0.1,), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', ax=ax3)
plt.title('Difficulty in Courses')
plt.ylabel("")

plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax4 = plt.subplot(2,2,4)
coursera_df_advanced["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',shadow=True, explode=(0.1, 0), startangle=90,autopct='%1.1f%%', ax=ax4)
plt.title('Difficulty in Courses')
plt.ylabel("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer

```
f,a = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(8,8))
f.subplots_adjust(wspace = .8)

coursera_df_beginner["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',
                                                                    shadow=True, 
                                                                    explode=(0.1, 0, 0), 
                                                                    startangle=90,
                                                                    autopct='%1.1f%%', ax=a[0,0])
a[0,0].set_title('Beginner Course')
a[0,0].set_ylabel('');


coursera_df_intermediate["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',
                                                                        shadow=True, 
                                                                        explode=(0.1, 0, 0), 
                                                                        startangle=90,
                                                                        autopct='%1.1f%%', ax=a[0,1])

a[0,1].set_title('Intermediate Course')
a[0,1].set_ylabel('');

coursera_df_mixed["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',
                                                                 shadow=True, 
                                                                 explode=(0.1,), 
                                                                 startangle=90,
                                                                 autopct='%1.1f%%', 
                                                                 ax=a[1,0])
a[1,0].set_title('Mixed Course')
a[1,0].set_ylabel('');

coursera_df_advanced["course_Certificate_type"].value_counts().plot(kind='pie',
                                                                    shadow=True,
                                                                    explode=(0.1, 0), 
                                                                    startangle=90,
                                                                    autopct='%1.1f%%', 
                                                                    ax=a[1,1])

a[1,1].set_title('Advanced Course')
a[1,1].set_ylabel('');
```